# FTP/Windows/COmmand Line

Tags: windows, command-line-interface, ftp

How do I connect to my ftpserver from command line in just one command line.

For Example : `ftp://hello.mydomain.com` is my ftp server URL. I usually open a command prompt

**Start -> Run -> cmd**

and type `ftp`, which gives me the ftp prompt.

```
ftp> open hello.mydomain.com
```

It asks me the user id and password

```
username: me  
password: onlyme
```

And then I connect. However, I am trying to connect automatically without having the user id and password prompt?

something like

```
ftp>open hello.mydomain.com --username me --password onlyme
```

And it connects automatically without prompting the user ID and Password.

Answer (score 9):

Anyway, [this guy](http://www.petefreitag.com/item/77.cfm) shows exactly how to do it:

```
ftp -s:script.txt ftp.server.com
```

and the contents of script.txt could be:

```
your_username
your_password
bin
cd /files
put file.zip
bye
```

where the first 2 lines of the file specify the username and password used for authentication.

Comment: I still think this should be moved to Serverfault.

Comment: Many sources say to use the FTP command "open ftp.server.com your_username your_password", which does not work. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old post however, one alternative is to use the command options:

`ftp -n -s:ftpcmd.txt`

the `-n` will suppress the initial login and then the file contents would be: (replace the 127.0.0.1 with your FTP site url)

```
open 127.0.0.1
user myFTPuser myftppassword
other commands here...
```

This avoids the user/password on separate lines

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can see, you can't do exaclty what you're asking. You can, however specify a list of commands in a seperate text file using the `-s:filename` argument.

Here's a list of command line arguments for the ftp utility:

http://www.nsftools.com/tips/MSFTP.htm

Take a look at this article which describes how to automate tasks using the ftp util:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows/how-to-automate-ftp-uploads-from-the-windows-command-line/

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use a different FTP program.  [Filezilla](http://filezilla-project.org/) Client works well for quick connects or you can save sessions with the username and password.

I believe there is also a command line interface if you didn't want to use the GUI.